# cannot implicitly convert type "void" to "UnityEngine.Vector2"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and have not used Unity that long. I am trying to have a projectile fire at my pointer, but it is firing closer to the base of my pointer. I have tried normalizing it by making a player, but I now keep getting this error and cannot find anything online that can help me

```
    private Rigidbody2D Player;
    public Rigidbody2D BallPrefab;
    public float attackSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float projectileSpeed = 500;

    void Fire() {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 playerPosition = Player.transform.LookAt(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 shootDirection = (mousePosition - playerPosition).normalized;

        Rigidbody2D ball = Instantiate(BallPrefab, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y),
      transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
        

      ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(shootDirection);
      Debug.Log(mousePosition);
    }
```

I have been trying to make a playerPosition, but after half an hour of trying different things, I can not figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Why do you think that you can assign "results" of void method to variable?

Comment: I've mostly been experimenting with different ideas that could fix it before getting stuck here, but I was hoping that by doing this, that it would normalize the projectile and shoot it where I wanted to go.

Comment: ref: `public void LookAt(Transform target);`  and: `You use void as the return type of a method (or a local function) to specify that the method doesn't return a value.`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is caused by this line of code
`Vector2 playerPosition = Player.transform.LookAt(Input.mousePosition);`
What this line of code is trying to do is set playerPosition to nothing (void). The function Player.transform.LookAt has return type void, so it doesn't return anything.

You only have to call the LookAt method to use it, it handles all the logic for you. Take a look at the Unity documentation if you want to have an example of how to implement it https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html